# How to pass multiple variables in a URL and have each one replaced by a default value if not supplied

Tags: php, get, default

In need of a little PHP help here.

The following PHP code works perfectly to pass an affiliate ID on a given website where the user adds their affiliate ID to the end of the URL, otherwise the default is used (I have been using this successfully).

Example:

> www.example.com (uses 'defaultid' from the PHP code)
>
> www.example.com/?id=test1 (uses the affiliate ID 'test1' supplied by
>   the user)

```
<?php

/* DEFAULT SETTINGS */

$DEFAULT_ID = "defaultid";

/* Function to display ID value */

function displayID($defaultValue) {

global $_GET, $DEFAULT_ID;

if (isset($_GET['id']) and strlen(trim($_GET['id']))) {

 echo $_GET['id'];

} else if (strlen(trim($defaultValue))) {

 echo $defaultValue1;

} else {

 echo $DEFAULT_ID;

}

}

/* End of function to display ID value */

?>
```

What I'd like to know is how to modify above code to work for 3 different affiliate IDs where there are 3 hyperlinks on a given web page for 3 different affiliate offers.

Example:

> www.example.com  (uses 3 default IDs that I've defined in the code)
>   www.example.com/?id1=test1 (uses default IDs 'defaultid2' and
>   'defaultid3') www.example.com/?id1=test1&id2=test2 (uses just the
>   default ID 'defaultid3') 
>   www.example.com/?id1=test1&id2=test2&id3=test3 (uses the 3 IDs
>   supplied in the URL by the affiliate)

Please note I am not PHP savvy, so a modification of the above code would be preferred (if possible), rather than a complete rewrite that I may not understand.

Comment: You could loop through the `$_GET` array and parse each one or you could use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to have a default value you can add this to your code:

```
$id1="test1";
$id2="test2";
$id3="test3";

if (isset($_GET['id1']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id1'])))
   $id1=$_GET['id1'];

if (isset($_GET['id2']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id2'])))
   $id2=$_GET['id2'];

if (isset($_GET['id3']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id3'])))
   $id3=$_GET['id3'];
```

How this code works: You have three variables, one for each `ID`.

The conditional will verify if there is anything in the `$_GET` array with the name for this `id`. If there is, it will overwrite the previous value, and if not, the default value will remain in there.

Also, if you're a fan of ternary, this does the same and looks prettier:

```
$id1= (isset($_GET['id1']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id1']))) ? $_GET['id1'] : "test1";
$id2= (isset($_GET['id2']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id2']))) ? $_GET['id2'] : "test2";
$id3= (isset($_GET['id3']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id3']))) ? $_GET['id3'] : "test3";
```

Comment: Thanks Jay & Phiter for your responses.

Comment: Don't forget to pick an accepted answer, if it helped.

Comment: With the example you have given above Phiter, presumably I can just introduce it to my current code?

Comment: Yes, you can use this exact code. Just change the default values as you wish, then proceed to use the `$id1`, `$id2`, `$id3` in the rest of your code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Phiter. appreciate that.  I'll have a play later this evening.

Comment: Hi Phiter, just letting you know that using your suggestion I managed to achieve the result I wanted (maybe not exactly as you coded it above), but certainly it was instrumental in solving my problem.